# Fetch data using mongoose and Express/Node Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am trying to fetch data from a MongoDB database using mongoose and express in Node js ,  i created the Model and successfully connected to database but the problem is i am getting an empty response while there already documents in the database collection .

Model class :

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const RendezvousSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    idpatient: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    idmedecin: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Rendezvous", RendezvousSchema);
```

index.js :

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Rendezvous = require("../model/RendezVous");
/* Get Rendez Vous By id */
/**
 * @method - GET
 * @description - Get Rendez vous Medecin
 * @param - /user/GetRdvMedecin
 */
router.get("/GetRdvMedecin", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const rdv = await Rendezvous.find();
    res.json(rdv);
    console.log('Fetched');
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({ message: "Error in Fetching rendez vous" });
  }
});
/* Get Rendez Vous By id*/
module.exports = router;
```

this is the console.log :

```
Server Started at PORT 4000
Connected to DB !!
Fetched
```

Postman GET request on : 'http://localhost:4000/user/GetRdvMedecin'

Postman Response : ' [] '

document sample :

```
{
  "_id":{
    "$oid":"5e7396787b32a12e38a7aa7d"
  },
  "idpatient":"5e6ce11bc31de6132ca454a1",
  "idmedecin":"5e5aa519190d8c2818a66a0a"
}
```

Hint : when i used another model ('user')  it works fine and returns a response .

Comment: try to add res.send({rdv}) OR  res.send(JSON.stringify(rdv))

Comment: Can you show your connection bit?

Comment: @Zlatko you mean the database connection code ?

Comment: Yes, wherre do you start the server and connection?

Comment: in another file , there is no problem with the databse connection i already fetched and everything is working fine , i am just having a problem with this method .

Comment: @MayankPandav the problem is not with the format sent as response the problem that there is no data fetched .

Comment: you have created an schema , but doesnot seems to be using it while fetching the data, change `await Rendezvous.find();` to `await RendezvousSchema.find();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by  adding the name of collection in the model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const RendezvousSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    idpatient: {
        type: String
    },
    idmedecin: {
        type: String
    }
},{
    collection: 'Rendezvous'
});

// export model user with UserSchema
module.exports = mongoose.model("Rendezvous", RendezvousSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request .find() could return more than one object, I always return something like this:

```
router.get("/GetRdvMedecin", async (req, res) => {
 let results;
 try {
    results = await Rendezvous.find();
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({ message: "Error in Fetching rendez vous" });
  }
  res.json({rendezvous: results.map(result => result.toObject({getters: true}) )});
});
```

Comment: still no results  , {"rendezvous":[]}

Comment: are you sure that you have data on database

Comment: yes sure of that , i did insert in the same collection and it worked fine

Comment: I think that you are not getting data from the database, try to print on console.log(result), result that you think you are getting from database, on my case on try{ result ...... console.log(result); } just to test if you are getting data from database, which I think you are not getting any data